# Node delay retry requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, delay

I'm trying to retry requests after a failed one.  However, I want to delay the request.  I haven't been able to make `setTimeout` work because my function tests the returned json (and it's recursive) and setTimeout doesn't return the return value of the callback.

```
function makeRequest(req, nextjson, attempts){
  // I'm using a different method here
  get({url: "http://xyz.com", json: nextjson},
    function(err, json2){
      if(err===200){
        return json2
      } else {
        // json2 might be bad, so pass through nextjson
        if(attempts < 5){
          return makeRequest(req, nextjson, attempts+1)
        } else {
          // pass back the bad json if we've exhausted tries
          return json2
        }
      }
   })
}
```

I want to delay the execution of the recursive call.  Also, I'm a bit embarrassed by this code.  Way too imperative.  If you have ways to clean it up, I'd appreciate that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a value from the `setTimout` function, you will have to rewrite your function to utilize callbacks:

```
function makeRequest(req, nextjson, attempts, callback) {
    // I'm using a different method here
    get({
        url: "http://xyz.com",
        json: nextjson
    }, function (err, json2) {
        if (err === 200 || attempts === 5) {
            callback(json2);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                makeRequest(req, nextjson, attempts + 1, callback);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

And call it like so:

```
makeRequest(requestStuff, jsonStuff, 0, function(result){
    // do stuff with result
});
```

I should add, your `get` function is an asynchronous function (evident by the callback being passed in), so as it stands, your `makeRequest` function will never return anything, as the `get` request will only complete after the `makeRequest` function has already been executed. You must use callbacks to access the values returned by an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try rate limiter for throttling your calls.  You will not get a token to move forward if you have breached the limit.

```
https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter
```

**Example:**

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
// Allow 150 requests per hour. Also understands
// 'second', 'minute', 'day', or a number of milliseconds
var limiter = new RateLimiter(150, 'hour');

// Throttle requests
limiter.removeTokens(1, function(err, remainingRequests) {
  // err will only be set if we request more than the maximum number of
  // requests we set in the constructor

  // remainingRequests tells us how many additional requests could be sent
  // right this moment

  callMyRequestSendingFunction(...);
});
```